# RenderScript custom ScriptC slower than Intrinsics

Tags: android, renderscript

I created a very simple grayscale script, and it takes more time than the intrinsics blur to render. Why ?

grayscale.rs:

```
#pragma version(1)
#pragma rs java_package_name(com.nanotapsoft.cartooncamera)

#pragma rs_fp_relaxed

uchar4 __attribute__((kernel)) grayscale(uchar4 pixelIn, uint32_t x, uint32_t y) {
    uchar grayscale = (pixelIn.r + pixelIn.g + pixelIn.b) / 3;  // simple average
    //uchar grayscale = pixelIn.r * 0.299 + pixelIn.g * 0.587 + pixelIn.b * 0.114;

    uchar4 pixelOut;
    pixelOut.a = pixelIn.a;
    pixelOut.r = grayscale;
    pixelOut.g = grayscale;
    pixelOut.b = grayscale;

    return pixelOut;
}
```

Call in java :

```
    t1 = System.currentTimeMillis();

    iBmp.copyFrom(tmpbmp);

    blurscript.setInput(iBmp);
    blurscript.forEach(oBmp);

    oBmp.copyTo(tmpbmp);

    t2 = System.currentTimeMillis();
    System.out.println("Blur: " + (t2-t1));

    t1 = System.currentTimeMillis();

    iBmp.copyFrom(tmpbmp);
    grayscaleScript.forEach_grayscale(iBmp, oBmp);
    oBmp.copyTo(tmpbmp);

    t2 = System.currentTimeMillis();
    System.out.println("Grayscale: " + (t2-t1));
```

I get an average of 12ms for blur and 28ms for grayscale

Comment: What blur radius are you using when comparing?

Comment: I use blurscript.setRadius(5f); But whatever radius i set, the grayscale should take less time because it's a simpler process. Or is there a more optimized code for the grayscale script ?

Comment: In that case it sounds in-built intrinsic kernels do use some special optimisations not available for the rest of us. Your grayscale kernel seems somewhat speedy one would expect outperforms blur hands down.

Comment: Perhaps. I did a simple grayscale script based on YUV input and it's 5x faster than this one.

Comment: What is the origin of the Allocation? Camera preview by any chance?

Comment: @MiloslawSmyk, Allocation is instanciated in the onSurfaceChange method

Comment: probably, you should have chained blur and grayscale scripts; your code performs unnecessary copy of the bitmap between CPU memory and GPU memory.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For those who want a faster grayscale renderscript, if you use YUV data you can get up to 5x faster :

```
#pragma version(1)
#pragma rs java_package_name(com.nanotapsoft.cartooncamera)

#pragma rs_fp_relaxed

rs_allocation ain;
rs_allocation aout;

rs_script grayscaleYUVScript;

void root(const uchar *v_in, uchar4 *v_out, const void *usrData, uint32_t x, uint32_t y) {

    uchar yp = rsGetElementAtYuv_uchar_Y(ain, x, y) & 0xff;
    v_out->r = yp;
    v_out->g = yp;
    v_out->b = yp;
    v_out->a = 0xff;
}

void filter()
{
    rs_allocation ignored;
    #if !defined(RS_VERSION) || (RS_VERSION < 14)
        rsForEach(grayscaleYUVScript, ignored, aout, 0);
    #else
        rsForEach(grayscaleYUVScript, ignored, aout);
    #endif
}
```

Average execution time of this script is about 7ms for the same input size of the first script I used.